# What is the DC for the "Thorn Burst" ability for a Wood Oracle?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, oracle

The "Thorn Burst" ability of the Wood Oracle reads:

> Thorn Burst (Su): As a swift action, you can cause sharp splinters of wood to explode outward from your body. These splinters deal 1d6 points of piercing damage per two oracle levels (minimum 1d6) to all creatures within a 10-foot burst. **A Reflex save halves this damage**. In addition, the sharp splinters count as caltrops in the area until your next turn. You can use this ability once per day, plus one additional time per day at 5th level and every five levels thereafter.

(emphasis added)

What is the DC for the reflex save in question?

Comment: I've edited your question to try and match site standards a little better.  I tried to preserve the misuses of terminology in case another answerer wants to tackle that, but if you feel I've occluded something essential to the confusion behind your question, please don't hesitate to edit it further.

Answer (score 6):

Thorn burst is a revelation of the Wood mystery. The [rules for revelations](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle?/#TOC-Revelation) state:

> Unless otherwise noted, the DC to save against these revelations is equal to 10 + 1/2 the oracle’s level + the oracle’s Charisma modifier.

Comment: Note that in most case DCs are 10 + 1/2 level + ability modifier. Sometimes there are subtleties like spells taking the spell level instead of 1/2 level, or other bonus stacking on top of that, but otherwise exceptions are rare.